# Do upvotes still count toward gaining tag badges after you hit daily cap?

Tags: support, badges, up-votes, daily-reputation-limit, tag-badges

If I reach the daily cap and still receive some upvotes for my answers, are they going to be counted toward me gaining some tag badge or are they lost? While I am not that fond of having lots of rep, I have an ambition of getting certain badges (I'd like to put that on my resume ;-)). So, is it 'beneficial' for me to do that after I hit the cap?

Comment: One additional point: Both upvotes *and* downvotes count. The tag badge vote total is all upvotes *minus* all downvotes on non-wiki answers in that tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, upvotes still count as votes, you just don't get rep from them.